# How to get value of object dynamically using a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a table of scores that need processing at certain points.  I am trying to avoid having walls of repetitive code so I am trying to get the values dynamically just by sending in the metric value but I cannot seem to get the syntax right and wasn't even sure how to properly search for this.

A typical value I need is something like this

```
s = score.total_weighted_strategic_values_score
```

All of these have the same structure to the name but one part changes based on the metric, so I have been trying something like this

```
s = score.total_weighted_"#{metric}"_score
```

Where `metric` is equal to a string `strategic_values` or whatever the metric is named.

This throws a syntax error, however, and I cannot find anything else to try.  any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This has been probably answered before, but try with `send` or `public_send` (depending on the method) `score.send("total_weighted_#{metric}_score")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use public_send:

```
s = score.public_send("total_weighted_#{metric}_score")
```

Some more reading on it:
http://vaidehijoshi.github.io/blog/2015/05/05/metaprogramming-dynamic-methods-using-public-send/

Comment: Wow that got solved fast, thanks for that works perfect! (I'll accept once I can)